# creating own calendar in JS by using the data as JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, date, calendar

The JSON will be generated dynamically.I am getting JSON data as

```
[{
  "date": "2016-04-01",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-02",
  "day_type": "HE",
  "reason": "Election"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-03",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "HOLIDAY WEEKLY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-04",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-05",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Mahaveer Jayandhi"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-06",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-07",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-08",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-09",
  "day_type": "HE",
  "reason": "Heavy Rain"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-10",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "HOLIDAY WEEKLY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-11",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-12",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-13",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Holi"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-14",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-15",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-16",
  "day_type": "HE",
  "reason": "Sports Day"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-17",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "HOLIDAY WEEKLY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-18",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-19",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-20",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-21",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": "WORKING DAY"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-22",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Govt Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-23",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-24",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-25",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-26",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-27",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-28",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-29",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-30",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-01",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Quarterly Holidays"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-02",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-03",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-04",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Chuma"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-05",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-06",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-07",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-08",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-09",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-10",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-11",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-12",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Leave"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-13",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Leave"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-14",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-15",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-16",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-17",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-18",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Chuma Leave"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-19",
  "day_type": "H",
  "reason": "Chuma Leave"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-20",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-21",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-22",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-23",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-24",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-25",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-26",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-27",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-28",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-29",
  "day_type": "HW",
  "reason": "Weekly Holiday"
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-30",
  "day_type": "W",
  "reason": null
}]
```

I want to display this as calendar.....

W-Working day, HW-Weekly holiday, HE-Holiday Evening, HM-Holiday Morning

The calendar has to be generated for these dates and reason should be displayed as tooltip and css should be set according to day_type...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to display calendar for those days and how to display events @Jason

Comment: I have tried with calendar plugin like full canendar. But it doesnt suits for me. @Alex